# meaning of "take the worst yourself"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Farewell; Charles sends you his best love, and Edward his worst. If
> you think the distinction improper, you may **take the worst yourself**.
> He will write to you when he gets back to his ship, and in the mean
> time desires that you will consider me as
>
> Your affectionate sister, J. A.

This is from [Jane Austen's letter to her sister Cassandra](http://book.99csw.com/book/136/4400.htm). I wonder what does "take the worst yourself" mean in this context.

Comment: I would guess that one of their brothers had said "Give her my best love", so another jokingly said "Give her my worst [love]". Jane's comment is just continuing the play on words, and doesn't mean anything in particular.

Comment: @verbose Your explanation makes  sense, but for the fact that when Jane wrote to Cassandra (20 november 1800) Charles and Edward were  Godmersham Park. So why would Charles send any kind of love to Edward who was there with him?

Comment: @TwoBob He isn't sending it to Edward, but to Cassandra via Jane's letter. (At least, that's how I read it - Verbose seems to have read it differently.)

Comment: @KateBunting I read it as you did initially, but after I'd read verbose's answer I realised that the idea that Charles is sending his best love to his sister and his worst to his brother is not only possible but makes lots of sense. I do like the idea that if you have 'best love' to give you must also have 'worst love' available. Back when people talked about 'best butter' and, even now about 'best bitter' I've been tempted to ask for 'a pound of 'your worst butter' or a pint of 'your worst bitter'. People often used to ask butchers for 'a nice piece of steak' which I always thought odd too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just extending Charles’s joke.

Jane tells Cassandra that Charles sends his love, but with a distinction: “best love” to Cassandra herself, “worst love” to Edward. This is a joke because generally one sends “love” or “best love”. There isn’t such a thing as “worst love”—the phrase is oxymoronic. But if one has a teasing relationship with a sibling or other family member, one could tease that person by saying “I send you love. Not good love, just my worst love.”

That’s what Charles does to Edward. But since the letter is to Cassandra and not to Edward directly, he tells Jane to tell Cassandra that if she does not want to tell Edward that Charles sends him his “worst love” because she might consider such teasing improper, then Cassandra herself can keep the “worst love” and let Edward have the best that he (Charles) had sent to Cassandra.